# reading parquet to pandas FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, parquet

I have code as below and it runs fine. It reads as a spark dataframe

```
April_data = sc.read.parquet('somepath/data.parquet')
type(April_data)
pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
```

But when I try to read as a pandas df I get error

```
df_pp = pd.read_parquet('somepath/data.parquet')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_4244/1910461502.py in <module>
----> 1 df_pp = pd.read_parquet('somepath/data.parquet')

/usr/local/anaconda//parquet.py in read_parquet(path, engine, columns, storage_options, use_nullable_dtypes, **kwargs)
    498         storage_options=storage_options,
    499         use_nullable_dtypes=use_nullable_dtypes,
--> 500         **kwargs,
    501     )

/usr/local/anaconda//io/parquet.py in read(self, path, columns, use_nullable_dtypes, storage_options, **kwargs)
    234             kwargs.pop("filesystem", None),
    235             storage_options=storage_options,
--> 236             mode="rb",
    237         )
    238         try:

/usr/local/anaconda/parquet.py in _get_path_or_handle(path, fs, storage_options, mode, is_dir)
    100         # this branch is used for example when reading from non-fsspec URLs
    101         handles = get_handle(
--> 102             path_or_handle, mode, is_text=False, storage_options=storage_options
    103         )
    104         fs = None

/usr/local/anaconda/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    709         else:
    710             # Binary mode
--> 711             handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
    712         handles.append(handle)
    713 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'somepath/data.parquet'
```

I have installed `fastparquet` package as below

```
!pip install fastparquet
Successfully installed cramjam-2.5.0 fastparquet-0.8.1
```

**# udpate 1**

the file is located in HDFS and I can see the file when I do

```
hdfs_location = 'somepath/'
!hdfs dfs -ls $hdfs_location
```

I am running all this code in the same file

Comment: If you, in python just before your `pd.read_parquet`, do `import os` and then do `print(os.getcwd())`. Does it give you the directory where you think `somepath/data.parquet` is?

Comment: Are you running the same lines in same script and environment? Traceback indicates Anaconda so you may be running virtualenvs. Please post a fuller script with enough context including all `import` lines.

Comment: Please check update1

Answer (score 3):

Per docs, [**`pandas.read_parquet`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html), similar to other sibling IO modules, does not support reading from HDFS locations. While there is [`read_hdf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf), it does not read parquet or other known formats.

For string values in `read_parquet`, CPU file paths or only online schemes (http, ftp) and two specific storage paths (Amazon S3 buckets, Google Cloud Storage or GS) are currently supported.

However, you can pass file-like objects. So consider reading the needed parquet file and pass content. Below are examples using various HDFS packages:

```py
from hdfs import Client

with client.read('somepath/data.parquet') as f: 
    df_pp = pd.read_parquet(f.read())
```

```py
from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem 
hdfs = HDFileSystem(host='localhost', port=8020)

with hdfs.open('somepath/data.parquet') as f: 
    df_pp = pd.read_parquet(f)
```

Also, [**`fastparquet`**](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) supports conversion to pandas data frame:

```py
from fastparquet import ParquetFile

pf = ParquetFile('somepath/data.parquet') 
df = pf.to_pandas()
```